# Javascript find and higlight text between [quote][/quote] within textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML code with pre-written message. My goal is to highlight text between [quote] [/quote] in a yellow background once I focus/click on the text area.

```
<textarea>
This is a test message.

[quote]Wise man said he is wise.[/quote] There could be more quotes too:

[quote]this is second quote [/quote]

He is correct.
</textarea>
```

Is it possible to do it with pure Javascript? I think it should be something like:

> textarea onfocus="function()">

- find text between [quote][/quote]
- apply yellow background to found text: background Color='#ffc'

....

*(and if there is no [quote] [/quote] found then it should do nothing, ie. no warnings).*

Comment: Why do you have to use `[quote]`. Use a class? Makes life easier.

Comment: This is a form that uses BB codes like [quote] or [i] for italic etc.. to style text within the text area.

Comment: Yeah so what is ultimately rendered in HTML? It must have some class.

Comment: take a look at this plugin: http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/

Comment: The question applies to textarea only; when user clicks within the text area he should have text between [quote] and [/quote] highlighted in yellow..

Comment: Text will be pasted, or user will type it? Click is not sufficient event if you want some kind of WYSIWYG editor...

Comment: Text will be pasted or will exist already (like when editing an existing post in a forum).

Answer (score 4):

Since you cannot do that using `<textatea>` i'd suggest to take a look at

```
<div contenteditable>

</div>
```

here's an example:

```js
var area = document.getElementById("area");
var text = area.innerHTML;

area.innerHTML = text.replace(/\[\s*quote.*\](.*)[^[]*\[\s*\/quote.*\]/ig, "<span>$1</span>");
```

```css
[contenteditable]{
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}
[contenteditable] span{
  background:#ffc;
}
```

```html
<div id="area" contenteditable>
This is a test message.

[quote]Wise man said he is wise.[/quote] There could be more quotes too:

[quote]this is second quote [/quote]

He is correct.
</div>
```

**Otherwise**, since you cannot treat HTML elements inside a `textarea` like actual HTML elements in order to highlight them → you should create an in-memory element with the same size (font-size etc) of your textarea, do the above, calculate the positions of the generated span elements, than apply some higlight overlays over the respective positions over your textarea, take care that they "follow-up" if the window resizes... and the story goes...

Here's a **jQuery plugin** to achieve the above-mentioned:
**http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/**

Comment: That's good even though I cannot change textarea to contenteditable - would this script work with textarea too?

Comment: @tom No. Read my updated answer. it's not possible to render HTML elements inside a textarea (like SPAN in order to highlight it) inside a `<textarea>`.

Comment: Ok I thought it can be done sine they do it with jquery... but it's useful for others so give you+1.

Comment: @Tom I'm a jQuery expert an I have no idea what you're referring to... Am I missing something?

Comment: Someone above posted link to: mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/

Comment: @Tom ahh I see. Exactly, and it works exactly as i've said in my Answer. Theres a wrapping DIV around the textarea, and inside that DIV there are the overlaying translucent elements that overlay the text. If you just add padding (in developer tools) to the textarea you'll see that the highlights are misplaced - But yes, that's exactly what I was talking about.

Comment: @Tom so there's tricks and plugins to achieve the desired *effect* (effect cause it's a visual hack) - for again, you cannot render HTML inside a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm investigating two approaches: [Highlight Text Inside a Textarea](http://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/), which describes how this plugin is done:  https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea

And syntax higlighter for MediaWiki:  [source](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Remember_the_dot/Syntax_highlighter.js), [description of approach](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Remember_the_dot/Syntax_highlighter#Overview_of_approach).

Both of them use additional element behind textarea with the same font and positioning to show background colors. Textarea background is made transparent. Then on edit and scroll you sync contents and scroll between textarea and element behind.

Here is my simplified code for it: https://codepen.io/bunyk-1472854887/full/RLJbNq/

Core logic of the highlighter is like this (some details skipped):

```
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', textUpdate);
textarea.addEventListener('scroll', scrollUpdate);

function textUpdate() {
    var html = html_escape(textarea.value);
    enter code here
    html = html.replace(/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/g, '[quote]<span class="quote">$1</span>[/quote]');

    background.innerHTML = html;
}

function scrollUpdate() {
    background.scrollTop = textarea.scrollTop;
};
```

Comment: Thank you - will wait.... : ) I only hope it would not use jquery.. : (

Comment: @Tom Sorry for making you wait so long. :)  I forgot to publish that code I come up with. But better late than never.